# How to get sum of array in foreach in laravel 6

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

from my controller sum is not working

```
public function show($id)
{

$workers = DB::table('workers')
->select('wrk_id','f_name','m_name','l_name')
   ;
$attendance = DB::table('attendance')->where('payroll_daily_id', $id)
->select('attendance.*','f_name','l_name','m_name',DB::raw('SUM(reg_hour)as tots'))
 
->rightjoinSub($workers,'worker', function($join){
    $join->on('attendance.wrk_id','=','worker.wrk_id');
})
->groupBy('payroll_attn_id')
->get();

  foreach($attendance as $key){
      $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['wrk_id'] = $key->wrk_id;
      $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['f_name'] = $key->f_name;
      $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['l_name'] = $key->l_name;
      $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['m_name'] = $key->m_name;
      $fetch['total_work_hours'] = $key->tots;
      $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['date'][$key->date]['work_hours'] = $key->reg_hour;
      
  }
  return $fetch;  


}
```

this is the `result total_work_hours` display only `8` instead of `56`

```
 2: {wrk_id: 2, f_name: "John", l_name: "Doe", m_name: null,…}
    date: {2020-09-27: {work_hours: 8}, 2020-09-28: {work_hours: 8}, 2020-09-29: {work_hours: 8},…}
    2020-09-27: {work_hours: 8}------------------
    2020-09-28: {work_hours: 8}------------------
    2020-09-29: {work_hours: 8}------------------
    2020-09-30: {work_hours: 8}------------------   TOTAL OF THIS IS 56
    2020-10-01: {work_hours: 8}------------------
    2020-10-02: {work_hours: 8}------------------
    2020-10-03: {work_hours: 8}-----------------
    f_name: "John"
    l_name: "Doe"
    m_name: null
    wrk_id: 2
    total_work_hours: "8" <-------------  56 is the total off work_hours from array
```

Comment: you want get 56 for all `work_hours` instead of 8 ?

Comment: yes exaclty....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $fetch = [];
    foreach($attendance as $key){
         if(!isset($fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_work_hours'])){
            $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_work_hours'] = 0;
          }
          $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['wrk_id'] = $key->wrk_id;
          $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['f_name'] = $key->f_name;
          $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['l_name'] = $key->l_name;
          $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['m_name'] = $key->m_name;
          $fetch['s'] = $key->tots;
          $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['date'][$key->date]['work_hours'] = $key->reg_hour;
          $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_work_hours'] += $key->reg_hour;
          
      }
      return $fetch;
```

Comment: not working `work_hours` gave me total of 16..  I want to get the total of all `work_hours` that result in the `total_work_hours` is `56`

Comment: It has error `Undefined index: total_work_hours", exception: "ErrorException"`

Comment: please check now

Comment: can you pls help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64024707/how-to-display-data-in-table-depends-what-date-where-it-belongs-in-laravel-and-v

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach like this:

```
foreach($attendance as $key){
     if(empty($fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_work_hours'])){
          $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_work_hours'] = 0;
     }
      $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['wrk_id'] = $key->wrk_id;
      $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['f_name'] = $key->f_name;
      $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['l_name'] = $key->l_name;
      $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['m_name'] = $key->m_name;
      $fetch['s'] = $key->tots;
      $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_work_hours'] += $key->reg_hour;   
  }
```

Comment: Updated the answer.